# Align last part of equation left, too

Tags: align

I have these equations:

```
\begin{flalign*}
p(C = c_1 | X = t) &= \frac{p(X = t | C = c_1) p(C = c_1)}{p(X = t)} &= \frac{\theta_1 \pi_1}{\theta_1 \pi_1 + \theta_2 (1 - \pi_1)} \\
p(C = c_1 | X = h) &= \frac{p(X = h | C = c_1) p(C = c_1)}{p(X = h)} &= \frac{(1 - \theta_1) \pi_1}{(1 - \theta_1) \pi_1 + (1 - \theta_2) (1 - \pi_1)}
\end{flalign*}
```

They look like this:

[image: That's not how I want it]

But I want the rightmost part to be aligned to the left.
Especially, I want the two last equals signs to be aligned, and move as far left as possible dragging the last part of the formular with them.
How do I do that?

Comment: You should use `\begin{alignat*}{2}` instead of `\begin{flalign*}` (with `\end{alignat*}`, of course); use `&&=` in front of the second `=`.

Comment: By the way, `flalign` should be used very sparingly; it's not a “catch-all” environment. Use the specific tool for the job.

Comment: Do you want your equations to begin at the left margin? This is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post a full working example next time.

You need to add a second &.
It's always alterning between right aligned and left aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
    p(C = c_1 | X = t) &= \frac{p(X = t | C = c_1) p(C = c_1)}{p(X = t)} &&= \frac{\theta_1 \pi_1}{\theta_1 \pi_1 + \theta_2 (1 - \pi_1)} \\
    p(C = c_1 | X = h) &= \frac{p(X = h | C = c_1) p(C = c_1)}{p(X = h)} &&= \frac{(1 - \theta_1) \pi_1}{(1 - \theta_1) \pi_1 + (1 - \theta_2) (1 - \pi_1)}
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** To get rid of the space before the last equation sign use the `alignat` environment as suggested by egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    p(C = c_1 | X = t) &= \frac{p(X = t | C = c_1) p(C = c_1)}{p(X = t)} &&= \frac{\theta_1 \pi_1}{\theta_1 \pi_1 + \theta_2 (1 - \pi_1)} \\
    p(C = c_1 | X = h) &= \frac{p(X = h | C = c_1) p(C = c_1)}{p(X = h)} &&= \frac{(1 - \theta_1) \pi_1}{(1 - \theta_1) \pi_1 + (1 - \theta_2) (1 - \pi_1)}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Space before second `=`sign? @egreg's comment gives right solution.